# Kitkat update on Nexus 4 fails

Tags: updates, nexus-4, 4.4-kitkat

*Hard to believe this is the first Kitkat installation question, but I don't find any. Sorry if it's a dupe!*

I feel like I'm too stupid to follow directions, but can you guys help me out here -- what am I doing wrong: I want to **update my Nexus 4 from stock 4.2.2 ROM to the new 4.4** [following these instructions](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/14/android-4-4-kitkat-factory-images-and-binaries-are-up-for-nexus-4-all-variants-of-nexus-7-2012-and-2013-and-nexus-10/). Note that the phone is rooted and runs Clockworkmod - I'm guessing this causes my problems but I need help to fix that.

I've got the downloads extracted and added the path to the bootloader so I can run the commands. But at the step that says `Reboot into the bootloader and run the appropriate flash-all script` it just says `waiting for device` forever.

The phone is in bootloader mode, but it's running Clockworkmod so I am guessing this is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble I encountered was that the `fastboot` program could not find my phone even though it was in bootloader mode. The solution was to run `fastboot` as sudo, but then the problem changed to be that sudo didn’t have the path to `fastboot` so I needed to give the explicit path to that as well: `sudo ./fastboot devices` worked (when I was in the directory android-sdk-linux/platform-tools). So I figured that I needed to change two things in the setup instructions:

1. run fastboot as sudo, and
2. add explicit paths in the flash script.

I've written a blog post that gives step-by-step instructions if anyone else needs this:
**[How to update your Nexus 4 to Android 4.4](http://torben.g-b.dk/2013/11/15/how-to-update-your-nexus-4-to-android-4-4.html)**